# Toggling enum values as bit flags

Tags: c, enums, typedef

I have a certain set of available enumed options

```
typdef enum { 
option1 = 1 << 0,
option2 = 1 << 1,
option3 = 1 << 2,
} availableOptions;
```

I want to toggle them off and on according to an input from the user before executing them.

For instance:

```
// iniatially set to all options
myOption = option1 | option2 | option3;
```

// after some input from the user

```
void toggleOption1()
{
  // how can I toggle an option that was already set without impacting the other options
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use bit-wise XOR:

```
void toggleOption1()
{
    myOption ^= option1;
}
```

The caret symbol `^` is the bit-wise XOR operator. The statement:

```
a ^= b;
```

flips only the bits in `a` where the corresponding bit in `b` is set. All other bits are left alone.

Comment: If I have the before and after values of all options - is it possible to know which options were toggled?

Comment: Maybe an example would be better:

Comment: originalOptions = option1 | option 2;
//After toggling
laterOptions = option1 | option3;

I understand that option2 was "turned off"

Comment: @AvnerBarr XOR to the rescue again... `oldOptions ^ newOptions` will also tell you which ones were flipped.

Comment: and then & with each of the option names ?